# Why is my HDMI audio not recognized?

Tags: 13.04, sound, pulseaudio, hdmi

On a previous installation my audio for HDMI did work, but on a fresh new install of Ubuntu desktop 13.04 my HDMI is not detected.

My goal is to get HDMI + analog audio simultaneously. I am using pulse audio with paprefs to get both of the audio devices playing together. It did not work because it did not find my HDMI audio at all. This is what I tried in a Terminal window:

```
htpc@htpc:~$ aplay -l
**** Lijst van PLAYBACK hardware-apparaten ****
kaart 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], apparaat 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Sub-apparaten: 1/1
  Sub-apparaat #0: subdevice #0
kaart 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], apparaat 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Sub-apparaten: 1/1
  Sub-apparaat #0: subdevice #0
kaart 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], apparaat 1: ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
  Sub-apparaten: 1/1
  Sub-apparaat #0: subdevice #0
htpc@htpc:~$ speaker-test -c 2 -r 48000 -D hw:0,3

speaker-test 1.0.25

Playback device is hw:0,3
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 2 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Playback open error: -19,Onjuist apparaat
```

I think this means my HDMI audio is detected but it can not play for some reason. Why is this?